# Selecting database base on row value

Tags: mysql

I want to know how can I select the amount value in base on the branch id? If the branch id is 1 I only want the amount that has branch id 1.

[image]

So here the first row of branch_id = 2 have amount of 24 so I only want to select the branch id column and amount column base on the branch id value.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get only 2 column, branch_id and total amount,
you can use the code below

Select branch_id,sum(amount)
from
yourtable(your table name)
group by
branch_id

Comment: Hi actually I want to know how can i get the total sale for each branch or total amount. Thank you for your input.

Comment: this code will give you,(brunch_id amount_total
1  90
2  60
3  33
)

Comment: Thanks, a lot Yusuf.